# Sending zipped file Spring

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, zip

I would like to send an already existing zipped file through my spring controller but I keep getting these error messages `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation` or a  `NoHandlerFoundException` which results in a 404 response. Is there something that I am missing? This is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = BASE + "/download",
        produces = "application/zip"
)
@ResponseBody
public void sendZippedFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    try{
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\me\\test.zip");
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=" + file.getName());
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        FileCopyUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    }catch (IOException e){
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Break points in my method are not even being reached.

Comment: Can we get more precision on the errors? Like, where do they fire, and where do your program stops? Alsoi, the catch clause isn't reached?

Comment: Hmmm... I had a typo in my endpoint while I was testing, that is why the errors were happening sorry.

Comment: You should close your question then :p Glad you found the error. (closing the question is just so that other users don't end up on this question while looking for help ^^)

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this :

```
@RequestMapping("/download")
public void download(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\me\\test.zip"));

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.zip\"");
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);

        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
}
```